# Could this MYSQL be optimized?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, full-text-search

Hello I'm having a comments table on which I run a fulltext search.
c1 and c2 are aliases on the same table used
via criteria: c1.parent_id=0 I get the questions only(not the answers attached to them)
and via c2.parent_id<>0 I filter the questions that already have answers

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.comment, c1.comment_id, MATCH(c1.comment) AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2 keyword3') AS score 
    FROM comments AS c1 
        JOIN comments AS c2 
            ON c1.comment_id = c2.parent_id 
    WHERE c1.parent_id=0 
        and c2.parent_id <> 0 
    ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 9
```

The problem is that when I run EXPLAIN SELECT... the search looks up through each and every row of the table - so the bigger it gets the slower this operation will be, instead of searching just the rows with parent_id=0.

I would like to ask: is it possible to optimize this kind of query any further?

Comment: Could you provide the full table definition and EXPLAIN output?

Answer (score 0):

add an index to all the id columns

```
    alter table your_table add index(parent_id)
```

same with comment_id

Comment: well, same result. I've been using: CREATE INDEX test ON comments (comment_id,parent_id);

Comment: The order of columns is very important in an index. The comment_id is unique, I guess, so the INDEX test ON comments (comment_id,parent_id) doesn't really do much. Try hforbess' suggestion CREATE INDEX test2 ON comments (parent_id), try a new EXPLAIN and see that the index is used now.

Comment: Well I've tried only using index on(parent_id) the result is the same. Out of 2000 rows around 700 searched - where they have to be filtered up to 175. It's interesting that if I filter them further via c1.category = 'cat1' the result is around 700, but if the filter is via c2.category = 'cat1' the mysql goes trough the all 2000 rows.